# I would like to know when to use have and has in a sentence talking about a country

Tags: singular-vs-plural, proper-nouns, dialect

Jamaica has or have snakes?
Which is correct?
Explain

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you find confusing about this?

Comment: Jamaica is a country and a singular noun, which means a singular verb shall be used after it (like in "Japan has four distinct seasons" or "America's got talent" ("has got" but not "have got").

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the verb agrees with the subject in number, so

> This region has snakes.
>
> Those regions have snakes.

Countries are normally singular:

> Jamaica has snakes.

even if grammatically they look plural:

> The Seychelles has snakes.
>
> The United States has snakes.

What might be confusing you is that collective nouns (nouns denoting a collection of people) sometimes take a plural verb when the sense is that your are talking about  what the people do or are, rather than what the group as a whole is:

> Manchester United has/have scored a goal.
>
> The committee is/are worried.

And this can even apply to names of countries when it means a the national team in some competition:

> Jamaica has/have scored a goal.

Using plural in these cases is more common in British than American English.